# Coupon code auto generation unable to find

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

I have a coupon code that exists in magento (version 1.9.2.3). I think it it was created with auto generation. At least that is what I guess, because I cannot create a new one and I cannot find it using the filter in the admin panel.

My question is: how can I find out which coupon that is? How can I search/filter them in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find the rule in the adminpanel.

You can search directly in the Database. All auto generated codes are in the Table `salesrule_coupon`. With this Query you can find the Rule ID:

```
SELECT rule_id FROM salesrule_coupon WHERE code = "YOUR_CODE_HERE"
```

The output is the Rule ID. You can filter the ID in the Shopping Cart Price Rules Grid

**//edit**
If you want to implement this feature in your adminpanel, you could rewrite the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Grid`. In `_prepareCollection`, you have to join the `salesrule_coupon` table and create and add a filter to the `coupon_code` Column:

> 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterMassCouponCode')

In the `private function _filterMassCouponCode($collection, $column){}` you can add your own filter.

Comment: Why is magento not able to do that. I know I can find it in the database. But if some else is looking for this, he always has to come to me.

Comment: I think the mass coupon feature was implemented after the basic module was created and the Grid is just the basic grid. So its just a addon to the salerules. I edited by answer add a solution how you could implement this feature.